# Is it possible to import the json files from mapbox studio (the custom map one) to Google maps?

Tags: json, google-maps, import, mapbox, mapbox-studio

I am trying to import the json file to Google maps from mapbox studio but nothing changes, the colors are not changing at all. Do you know if I did something wrong?

Part 1 : Getting the .json file

If you go to mapbox, you can customize the style of you map in the studio.
Once it's done, you can click on the "share" button on top right corner of the page.

This open a modal, on this modal, on the left column, you have 5 tabs under Developer Resources.

With the Web tab selected (doesn't matter), you can download a .zip file, which contains a json file.

This is the styling code for the map.

Part 2 : Trying to set this style to a google map

On the Google Maps Platform, on the left side menu, the last link of the list is Map Styles.
When you click on this link, you can create a new map style.

And then you can choose To create your own style with google maps, or Import Json.

So I clicked on import json, and paste the whole json file inside, but the map preview don't look like my custom map.

Maybe mapbox and google maps json styling file are not compatible?
Maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: Well, On the mapbox studio page, you can export the map styling file, wich is a json file. And google have a textarea field to paste the whole json file. should i paste the whole json file here? 
I don't know if it can help but i'll do this. Thanks for the answer btw.

Edit:  this json file is too long.

Comment: I don't know: what mapbox page you are taking about, what JSON, what textarea and where. That's the point I was trying to make with my dumb comment above. Without more information, I doubt you'll get any sort of help.

Answer (score 1):

If you would have checked the [JSON style specification from Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference) and the [JSON style specification from Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/) you would have seen they have only in common the word JSON, so the answer is NO, each one have their own definition for styling their maps.